# Let $A = ${$r \in \mathbb Q :\, \sqrt3 < r \le 5 \}$. What is the $\inf A$ and $\sup A$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, upper-lower-bounds

Let $A = ${$r \in \mathbb Q :\, \sqrt3 < r \le 5 \}$. What is the $\inf A$ and $\sup A$?

So off the top of my head without writing a proof, I would assume that the $\inf A$ wouldn't be $\sqrt3$ because it is not a rational number. So I am not sure what the inf A should be. And then for the $\sup A$, I would assume $5$ is the $\sup A$ and that should be alright since it is a rational number in the set $A$.

For the proof though, I am unsure how to prove it. I am guessing I would have to show that whatever the $\inf A$, that it is the greatest lower bound and then for the $\sup A$ which I believe is $5$, that it is the least upper bound.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98795/discussion-on-question-by-johnny-let-a-r-in-mathbb-q-sqrt3-r-le).

Answer (score 2):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what $\inf$ means.

If $A$ is a set that is bounded below, there is *nothing* in the definition that says $\inf A \in A$.  In fact, so often do we have $\inf A \not \in A$ that one might say that is the entire point of $\inf$.

The definition of $\inf A$ is that i) for every $a\in A$ we have that $\inf A \le a$.  (In other words, $\inf A$ is a lower bound.)  In this case $\sqrt 3 < a$ for all $a \in A$.

and ii) that $\inf A$ is the largest such number that is.  That is if $y > \inf A$ then $y$ is *not* a lower bound.  Or in other words if $y > \inf A$ there will be a $b\in A$ so that $\inf A \le b < y$.

For example $1$ is a lower bound of $A$ because if $\sqrt 3 < a \le 5$ then $1 < a$.  But $1 \ne \inf A$ because $1.2 > 1$ and $1.2$ is *also* a lower bound so $1$ is not the *greatest* lower bound.

Now what about $\sqrt 3$?  If $y > \sqrt 3,$ then can we find a rational number $b\in A$ so that $\sqrt 3 < b < y$?  I mean if $y= 1.8$ then we can have $b = 1.74$ and if $y = 1.733$ we can have $b=1.7321$ and so on.

Is there any $y > \sqrt 3$ where $y$ is a lower bound?

If not, then $\sqrt 3$ is the *greatest* lower bound.

That $\sqrt 3$ is not rational and $\sqrt 3 \not \in A$ is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Just confused because in class we had an example that basically we were looking at A = {$a \in Q : a^2 < 2$} and we got to the point that sup A = $\sqrt2$, but since $\sqrt2$ isn't a rational number, then A had no sup in $Q$.

Comment: @Johnny:  and in this question $A$ has no $\inf$ in $\Bbb Q$ either.  It has an $\inf$ in $\Bbb R$.  That is why Gae asked what set you are working in.  We can define your $A$ as a subset of $\Bbb R$, even though all its elements are rational.

Comment: Yes, $\{a\in \mathbb Q: a^2 < \}$ has not $\sup$ in $\mathbb Q$ but it *DEFINITELY* has a $\sup$ in $\mathbb R$.  That's *why* $\mathbb R$ *exists*.  It is a *complete* space so every bounded above set will have a $\sup$ in $\mathbb R$.  And the $\sup$ of $\{a\in \mathbb Q: a^2 < \}$ is *INDEED* $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I do admit that I made an assumption that you are working in $\mathbb R$ (which is complete).  But if you are working in $\mathbb Q$ then you need to *state* that in the question.  In that case that (as $\mathbb Q$ is incomplete) the $\inf $ of the set need not exist and in this case it doesn't. But $\sup$ of the set is $5$.

Comment: "but since 2–√ isn't a rational number, then A had no sup in Q."  Was that the "moral" of the class lecture?  It is true that bounded sets need not have sups in $\mathbb Q$ but I don't think that is a very important life lesson.  I'd think the *real* moral is that a bounded set of rational numbers will always have a $\sup$ but it need not be an element of the set nor does it need to be rational.  It could be irrational. And the *BIG* moral is that *every* real number (irrational or not) *is* the $\sup$ of some set of *only* rational numbers.

Comment: Consider $x\in \mathbb R$.  and let $A=\{q\in \mathbb Q| q \le x\}$.  Then $\sup A = x$ whether $x\in \mathbb Q$ or not.  In fact $B=\{q\in\mathbb Q|q<x\}$ is such $\sup B = x$.

Comment: +1 for the BIG moral comment. The set of reals is constructed precisely to fix the problem that many bounded subsets of $\mathbb {Q} $ have no inf/sup in $\mathbb {Q} $.

Comment: I mean.  If the class showed that $\{q\in \mathbb Q|q^2 < 2\}$ has no $\sup$ in $\mathbb Q$, can't imagine that the point *wasn't* to explain that it *does* have an irrational $\sup$ in $\mathbb R$ and that indeed that $\sup \{q|q^2 < 2\} =\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not stated explicitly in the question, the usage of symbol $\sqrt{3}$ suggests that you are working in the system of real numbers. In that case as you have rightly guessed $\inf A=\sqrt{3},\sup A=5$.

In case you wish to deal with this problem within $\mathbb{Q} $ then you should state this explicitly and avoid usage of symbol $\sqrt{3}$. The set $A$ can then be defined as $$A=\{x\mid x\in\mathbb {Q}, 0<x\leq 5,x^2>3\}$$ And then it is trivial that $\sup A=5$ but not so easy to prove that set $A$ does not possess an infimum in $\mathbb {Q} $.